# Google Script : How to add an image to a CheckboxItem choice programmatically?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, image, checkbox

In a Google Form, you can manually add an image to the choices in an checkbox item (there is a little icon appearing on the right when you manually edit one choice). I would like to do that programmatically but I could not find any way in the [reference guide](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/choice).

I need it because using `getChoices` and `setChoices` of the `CheckboxItem` makes the manually set images vanished every time I need to filter its choices.

Is it just not possible or is it only for some sort of premium users?